# Google Maps 'API key' problem

Tags: google-maps

I finally got this google maps page working however, it seems that everybody except the client can see it? They're saying the following error message appears "This web site needs a different Google Maps API key. A new key can be generated at..."

Here's the page: http://www.sportingemporium.com/google-map.htm

When I sign-up for a new key Goggle gives me exactly the same one that I am already using!

If anyone can shed any light on why I (and colleagues in many different countries) can see the map, but the client can't, it would be greatly appreiciated?

Kind regards,
Declan Bradley

Comment: I can see it in Google Chrome and IE.  Maybe your client needs to do a hard refresh of the page (CTRL+F5 in most browsers).

Comment: Also, from the Maps API generator: `Tip: Signing up a key for http://yourdomain.com is usually the best practice, as it will work for all subdomains and directories. See this FAQ for more information.`

Answer (score 1):

Check how they access your web site.  The key is tied to a web site address.  If instead of using www.sportingemporium.com or just sportingemporium.com they are using something like beta.sportingemporium.com, Google maps will complain.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies, unfortunately, even with a hard refresh and including and omitting the www in the domain name, there's no sign of the map, just the error message asking for a new API key. I just asked a friend in Germany to check it, no problem! But the client still can't see it! ...the search continues!

Comment: Try changing the top level domain to match that of the country where your client is located.  For instance, instead of maps.google.com, if your client is in Canada, try maps.google.ca and see if that changes things?